# What's stopping an app from using another platform's storage, for free?

Tags: licensing, api, data, storage, law

Let me clarify on a bit of an abstract question.

I'm about to develop an app, through which users can capture and store images. Commercially, the main cost here that springs to mind is storage cost.

There are platforms (e.g. facebook, dropbox, instagram) that may expose an API to allow consumers to upload images.

Which laws/licensing regulations are in place to prevent me from using *these* platforms (or platforms like it) for storage to avoid costs?

A few **key** points to make:

- My storage is in Azure, I'm wondering this purely theoretically. I don't plan on ever taking this approach, for a few reasons. It's just something I've always wondered.
- It may seem like the feasibility of this approach (or lack of) could render the whole hypothetical useless. But supposing a built in redundancy/fallback (i.e. used multiple platforms in the event of my data being snagged), it's feasible.

Comment: While you've gotten several answers already, I have voted to close this question because it as asking for legal advice. You really should seek the advice of a lawyer who has passed the Bar Exam, rather than anonymous software developers on the Internet.

Comment: *"the main cost here that springs to mind is storage cost"* -- clearly you've never had to pay a software engineer's salary. Human labor is the big cost. Storage is cheap.

Comment: @GregBurghardt -  "clearly"?! Don't be smug. I've already built it myself on the side to the tune of £0 salary costs.

Comment: Only because you have decided not to draw a salary. Consider for a moment that this expands and requires your full time attention. How much does it take to live and support yourself, and perhaps a family? Trust me. Storage costs are the least of your financial worries. Although since your labor is "free" at the moment, storage might be your *only* financial worry (hence I posted comments rather than answer the question).

Comment: @GregBurghardt - you're making massive assumptions again about my position, family set-up and the financial circumstances, so the comment's just not landing with any relevance, I'm afraid. Also, you seem closed off from the idea that infrastructure costs couldn't exceed the costs involved with a dev effort. Have you never encountered that before? I've worked on a hand full of platforms were this is most definitely the case. Not in the majority of cases, granted, but not uncommon enough for me to feel I could safely infra costs would only ever be the "least of worries" without knowing specifics

Comment: DanDev, I think you are missing the highest priority for any professional software developer: Getting paid good money.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm a professional software developer, getting paid good money from this app (specifically) is not my priority. Some people have means and ways of working on an app without it being their sole stream of revenue. Many ways, in fact. Lot of ignorance here, and it's rather off-topic too. There's no way people can conceivably assume enough about a personal situation to tell _me_ where my cost concerns lie. That's crazy. And I'm asking about storage specifically, let's try and keep this on topic now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something where there will be a law that says "you can't use facebook for hosting", that will be left up to the contract between facebook and you, i.e. their terms of use.

You might well find that for a small volume of images that you currently want to store, you *can* do exactly this. It would be prudent to look carefully at the terms, and have contingencies for what happens if you near or reach any limits that may be present.

The other likely scenario is the terms will include language along the lines of "We reserve the right to block access to users for *reasons*", i.e. if they find your use problematic, they can cut you off with no warning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the T&Cs for all free accounts will say "we reserve the right to suspend your account without notice because we feel like it" or words to that effect; whatever limits may be stated in the T&Cs are mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @PhilipKendall hence the "look carefully"

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting idea, not for the commercials but for potential anonymous distributed storage.

The problem of course is you would run afoul of the Terms and Conditions of any site you used and presumably have your accounts periodically banned and data deleted.

To deal with that you would have to automate account creation and data upload, this would require than you bypassed captcha and other bot protection on those sites.

Its not impossible, but you would be fighting a war against the various sites you used and would have to constantly update your application in response to their changes. Given that things like bit torrent exist I don't think its will be a viable option for most applications.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to allow your users to store the images in their own Facebook/Instagram/Dropbox/etc. accounts, then there is no legal hindrance to develop such a system.

On the other hand, if you intend to use *your own* account as backing storage, copyright law is one thing to consider from a legal viewpoint, especially in combination with the type of content that the provider allows a user to upload (only what they created themselves, or also third party works) and what rights you give the provider when uploading something. Just because someone created an image in/with your app does not mean you have anything to say, in a legal sense, about what may happen next to that image.